# Why does this string not match the pattern

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I expected the word `'789'` to match my pattern `'\b[7][8-9]{2}\b'` in the following example:

```
def test_4(self):
    text = 'asdf 2345 gfdf 44 dfg 79878 dsfg 78998 sdfg 789 7989 '
    pattern = '\b[7][8-9]{2}\b'
    match = re.search(pattern, text)
    if match:
        print(pattern)
        print(match.group())
```

Why does the text not match the pattern?

Comment: use `r'\b[7][8-9]{2}\b'`

Comment: So you're looking for a word boundary, then a `7` followed by two numbers (either `8` or `9` ) and then you want to look for another word boundary?

Comment: @RNar this nailed it, thx!

Comment: @OnlineCop yes exactly

Comment: no problemo. its good practice to always use raw strings because things like \b can be read differently in python. you could also have done `\\` to escape all instances of `\` but thats just unecessary and gross

Comment: @RNar: When typing a backslash ``\``, use double `\``, then a backslash, then again double `\``.

Comment: oh, the irony of not realizing that i need to escape the backslash while talking about escaping blackslashes... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\b`s you have in your pattern string are being interpreted by Python as the ASCII backspace character (`'\x08'`) before the regex engine can see them and interpret them as a word break. In order to stop the first interpretation, use a "raw" string by prefixing the opening quotation mark with `r` (you could instead escape the backslash with an extra one, but that's usually uglier and less easy to understand than a raw string):

```
r'\b[7][8-9]{2}\b'
```

Note that the brackets around the `7` and the dash in the `[8-9]` are unnecessary (you could just use `r'\b7[89]{2}\b'`).